# Newton's root finding method that copes with stationary points

Tags: numerical-methods, roots, newton-raphson

I am using Newton's method to solve an equation of the form $y=f(x)$ for increasing values of $y$. The value of $x$ found for some $y$ is used for the next $y$ as a starting approximation and this works fine.

$f$ is increasing but may have stationary points, and I do have situations where the range of interest of $y$ starts or ends on an extremum or very close. This causes the algorithm to experience a division by zero or yield very inaccurate roots.

Is there a simple way to cope ? Is there a known modified Newton's method able to deal with this situation ?

I know that double roots can be handled by the modified iterations $$x\leftarrow x-2\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$$ but this still does not work at the root, and one needs to know when to activate the factor $2$.

[image]

For information, my function $f$ is a cubic polynomial, but I want to avoid the explicit computation of the roots by Cardano's formulas.

---

**Update:**

If we restate Newton's method at a stationary point, we get to the next term of Taylor's development,

$$f(x+h)-y\approx f(x)-y+\frac{h^2}2f''(x),$$

so that $$h\approx\sqrt{-\frac{f(x)-y}{f''(x)}}.$$

In fact, the approximation

$$f(x+h)-y\approx f(x)-y+h f'(x)+\frac{h^2}2f''(x)$$ always holds, giving the general formula

$$h\approx \frac{f'(x)\pm\sqrt{f'^2(x)-2f''(x)(f(x)-y)}}{f''(x)}.$$

Due to the increased complexity, I don't want to use that formula all the time.

Comment: Assuming $f(x)= ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, you know $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ and the roots of $f'(x)$. When $x$ approaches the roots of $f'(x)$, could you use l'hopital's rule and switch to $f'(x)/f''(x)$?

Comment: @PierreCarre: come on, in the interval of interest.

Comment: @PierreCarre: good point.

Comment: Incidentally, there' s an old but pretty good book, _Numerical Recipes_, that covers rootfinding in detail including various alternatives to Newton. You might be particularly interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method .

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: of course. I need very fast convergence (at most two iterations), otherwise the cost of the iterations might outweigh that of Cardano's approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Momentum-based algorithms are good at passing through stationary points while retaining fast convergence.

$$m_i=(1-\beta)f'(x_i)+\beta m_{i-1}=m_{i-1}-(1-\beta)(m_{i-1}-f'(x_i))$$
$$x_{i+1}=x_i-(1-\beta^i)\frac{f(x_i)}{m_i}$$

The $1-\beta^i$ factor serves as bias correction, supposing one takes $m_0=0$, since we get $m_i=(1-\beta^i)f'(x_i)$ if $x_i$ is fixed.

As $\beta\to0$, you get Newton's method and faster convergence, while for larger $\beta$ you will get better "resilience" against stationary points.

For your purposes, you know that $f'(x)\ge0$, so rather than setting $m_0=0$, you may want to initialize it to a small positive value, or perhaps even use the same $m_i$ sequence for every $y$, since it is likely you will converge to the solution for $y=f(x)$ for a given $y$ while $m_i$ is sufficiently large that starting from where it left off works well for the next $y$.

If you go with the latter approach, you'll want to choose $\beta$ based on the density of your $y$ around the stationary points. If $\beta$ is too small and you have many $y$ near a stationary point, then $m_i$ will decay rapidly, which leaves you with the original issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy modification called *modified Newton's method.* The idea is easy: every time the derivative is zero, one uses a value of the derivative from the last iteration, when it was nonzero (couple of times if needed). This changes the method to the secant kind of method for these couple of iterations. When it becomes nonzero again, one switches back to Newton's method. In more dimensions it works as well.

Additional thing, which you can always try in case of convergence problems, is the *damped* version of Newton's method. It means, that you reduce each increment by some fixed value smaller than $1$, for example by $0.9$.

Can you post the function you solve and your starting point?

Comment: Thanks. But what when you *start* the iterations at a minimum ? The functions are any cubic in a monotonic section, possibly starting or ending on an extremum. If you want a case, $-x^3+3x$ from $(-1,-2)$.

Comment: Interesting. Then you have to start from a different point. (Do you need to find one solution or all solutions?) You can try to generate starting points randomly in the solved domain and run Newton's method from these points unless you are successful.

Comment: Or you can try to examine functional value in more points (equidistantly spaced) and as a starting point choose the one, in which the value is closest to zero. Then you get a starting point of higher quality.

Comment: Yes, this is an option. In fact, for my application it is more natural to process by increasing $y$ and this is why I would prefer to have a solution that starts from the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the basic step is to solve the equation $f(x)-y=0$, for given $y$. If we are unsure of the multiplicity of a root, we can apply the modified Newton's method, which corresponds to the application of the usual Newton's method to $g(x)=\frac{f(x)-y}{f'(x)}$. This way, the quadratic convergence is recovered, at least in exact arithmetic. The iteration would be
$$
x_{n+1} = x_n-\dfrac{\frac{f(x_n)-y}{f'(x_n)}}{\frac{f'(x_n)^2 - (f(x_n)-y)f''(x_n)}{f'(x_n)^2} } = x_n - \dfrac{f'(x_n)(f(x_n)-y)}{f'(x_n)^2-f''(x_n)(f(x_n)-y)}
$$
If, by any chance, $f'(x_0)=0$, just move it  a bit.

Comment: $f'(x_0)=0$ (as well as $f'(x_0)\approx0$) is the topic of my question.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I understand. I'm just saying that using this method $f'(x_0)\approx 0$ does not pose a problem.

Comment: With $f'(x_0)=0$, the iterations don't start.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That is why I proposed that "If, by any chance $f'(x_0)=0$, just move it a bit". It would be part of the algorithm to check if $f'(x_0)=0$ and act accordingly.

Comment: I implemented it in Mathematica and it works fine.

Comment: If you want my question is about "how precisely can I move it a bit". When is $f'(x_0)$ considered negligible, and what to do exactly, in a way that blends with the normal case.

Comment: In my implementation, when $f'(x_0)=0$, I just moved $x_0$ by $\varepsilon>0$, where $\varepsilon$  was the tolerance used for Newton iterations. I suppose that better criteria can be obtained, but this one gets the work done. If $x_0$ is an extreme point in the interval, you can make it specifically move right or left. I also tried cases where $f'(x_0) = f''(x_0) = 0$.

Comment: You could probably get away with setting $f'(x_0)$ to $ε$ instead of evaluating $f'(x_0+ε)$ to save a few cpu cycles.